# rec FAIL sox: `default' Device or resource busy: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux

- System Environment：

```
   Static hostname: orangepizero
         Icon name: computer
  Operating System: Armbian 20.11.3 Focal
            Kernel: Linux 5.9.14-sunxi
      Architecture: arm`enter code here
```

root@orangepizero:~# rec test.mp3

Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:00.00 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0    rec WARN alsa: Input/output error
rec FAIL sox: `default' Device or resource busy: Operation not permitted
In:0.00% 00:00:00.00 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0
Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ALSA dsnoop plugin to record from an audio device which is already in use.

To specify the audio device using sox's rec command line application, use the "-t" flag like so :

`rec -t alsa dsnoop test.mp3`